# Unable to add SQLite in the VS13 Linq to SQL Classes

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2013

When i drag the table into the design surface it gives an error like **"The selected object(s) use an unsupported data provider."** i am using SQLite database in this project.
[image]

if this continues then how would i call a database table in my code using LINQ?

Comment: use entity framework instead of linq to sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DbLinq](https://github.com/dblinq/dblinq2007) to generate dbml files for SQLite and many other databases.